# how to filter set in search using mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 category

```
1.worker
2.staff
```

and i have 1 row of cardno

```
w12        (this is worker id format)
s109   and (this is staff id format)
```

and i want to show only staff id which start with `s` letter

how can i do this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM accounts 
where cardno 
AND date BETWEEN '$a' 
AND '$b' 
order by date ASC
```

Comment: What's the exact query you're running?  (add `echo mysql_error();` after the `mysql_query()` statement to see what's wrong with your query).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `LEFT`

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts
WHERE 
  DATE BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b'
AND LEFT(cardno ,1) ='s' /* or S */
ORDER BY DATE ASC
```

> Returns the leftmost len characters from the string str, or NULL if
>   any argument is NULL.

[**LEFT(str,len)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left)

Comment: i dont have staff row i have cardno row and i dont knw who is down vote to u

Comment: So change staff to cardno

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts
WHERE date BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b'
  AND cardno LIKE 's%'
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM accounts
WHERE cardno LIKE 's%'
  AND DATE BETWEEN '$a' AND '$b'
ORDER BY DATE ASC
```

The LIKE operator is used to search for a specified pattern in a column. 's%' means any word value that starts with s.

Comment: not working it is showing error Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in same line

Comment: Felipe: The question says `staff`, so why are you doing `WHERE cardno LIKE`? :)

Comment: @user3000993. Not sure what the problem can be. are you sure $a and $b arde defined?